# How can I pass data to stdin using C code?

Tags: c, stdin

I have an API function, which generate a new stdin input curse like >> . Because I have a lot of data already in memory in the form of array, how can I pass the data into the >> in C code? for example, getdatafromstdin is an API function, I do not know the details:

```
getdatafromstdin;
>>
```

This is normal form, but I do not want input data via keyboard, I want to pass data to >> by C code. Like

```
getdatafromstdin;
passdatatostdin;
```

Comment: Show some code and be more explicit, otherwise your question will certainly be downvoted and you won't get answers.

Comment: What's a *curse*? Did you mean input *prompt*?

Comment: yes, I mean the input prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are very little information in the question to be able to give a proper answer. One option is fixing `getdatafromstdin` to get a `FILE *` as argument instead of assuming `stdin`, so you can give a `FILE *` that you want. Another option is to divide the program into two parts. One that generates the input data and the other that uses `getdatafromstdin` and then pipe the two.

One easy to add option however if you don't want to do the others is a bit of cheating. You can write the data you want to feed to `stdin` to a file and then use [`freopen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/freopen) to reopen `stdin` to read from that file. Then calling your `getdatafromstdin` would read from that file.

If you pipe in `stdin` or `freopen` it, making it use the terminal later is not trivial. So I would recommend the first option (fix the `getdatafromstdin` function to get a `FILE *` parameter), but my guess is that it's not your own API.

Comment: thanks, because the getdatafromstdin is not my function, I can not get any information from it. It only invoke a input curse....I can input data via keyboard, but I prefer to do it using c code. btw, I'm under linux, is it possible obtain the shell curse and pass data ? and because there are lot of data writing them to a file and load it is very slow.....the data already existed as an array, I want to use it directly.

Comment: If you want to pass data only from the program and not by keyboard, yes. As I said, either write the data generator separately and use a pipe (`|`) when invoking the program (for example, `./generate_data | ./process_data`), or write the data to file and `freopen` to make `stdin` read from that file instead of the keyboard.

Comment: The program already has a input curse: it is like SQL environment. after the function getdatafromstdin there will be a second input curse, I want to use c code to fill in the second input curse. How can use the pipe?

Comment: With pipe, you completely redirect `stdin` from the beginning of the execution, which seems to be not what you want. I'd go with `freopen`.